# Why do I only receive the first message I send with SDLNet?

Tags: c++, sdl

I am sending two messages from server.exe like this:

```
sprintf( buffer,"%d %s",1,data1);
SDLNet_TCP_Send(clientSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1); // first message

sprintf( buffer,"%d %s",2,data2);
SDLNet_TCP_Send(clientSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1); // second message
```

and I am reading messages from client.exe like this:

```
if(SDLNet_CheckSockets(socketSet, 0)>0)
{
    if(SDLNet_SocketReady(clientSocket)>0)
    {
        if(SDLNet_TCP_Recv(clientSocket, buffer, 5000)>0)
        {
           //there i take only first message
        }
    }
}
```

Why am I not receiving all sent messages in the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client code is executed only once. I think you want `while` loop at the inner most `if`-statement instead, so something like:

```
if (SDLNet_CheckSockets(socketSet, 0)>0)
{
    if (SDLNet_SocketReady(clientSocket)>0)
    {
        while (SDLNet_TCP_Recv(clientSocket, buffer, 5000)>0)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no client.exe code already inside while but i am still taking only first message

Comment: like this while{if(SDLNet_CheckSockets(socketSet, 0)>0)
    {
        if(SDLNet_SocketReady(clientSocket)>0)
        {
            if(SDLNet_TCP_Recv(clientSocket, buffer, 5000)>0)
            {
               //there i take only first message
            }
        }
    } }

Comment: Well in that case I think you should show more of your code in the initial question.

Comment: sorry but you was right :D i take all messsages with your way thank you too much bro really thank you.